# Play Youtube Video in Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to have a YouTube video start playing as the iframe enters the viewport.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var inner = jQuery("#auto-video iframe");
    var elementPosTop = inner.position().top;
    var viewportHeight = jQuery(window).height();
   jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var elementFromTop = elementPosTop - scrollPos;

        if (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < elementPosTop + viewportHeight) {
            inner.get(0).play();
        } else {
           inner.get(0).pause();
        }
    });
```

This returns a "play is not a function" message in the console.

EDIT

```
<div id="auto-video">
   <iframe width="450" height="253" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wCdl3nGPDgE?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: can you post more code please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ZombieChowder, I have added the html that is calling the iframe

Comment: You shouldn't call the `play` method on the iframe, but instead, you have to use the YouTube Player API.

Comment: Ah I see, looks like  I have some reading to do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old thread, I found a solution and thought I'd post it in-case it's useful for anyone.

Using the code below, it will play the embedded YouTube video when the user scrolls to your element. Just fill in "#YourElement" with the element that will play the video when they scroll to it. Finally, give your iFrame and ID attribute and change "#YourIFrame" to whatever you called the ID of your iFrame.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 
//will trigger when your element comes into viewport
    var hT = $('#YourElement').offset().top,
    hH = $('#YourElement').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();



if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
    //appends &autoplay=1 to iFrame src, making it autoplay
    var videoUrl = $('#YourIFrame').attr('src');
    $('#YourIFrame').attr('src', videoUrl + "&autoplay=1");
}
```